# Spawning a Windows process from a WSL process in C

Tags: c, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a C project with client and server code. The client is cross platform, with Windows and Linux implementations. The server is Windows only.

I have integration tests that start the server and run operations from the client to the server. These tests are also written in C.

Is it possible using WSL to write a test which will execute in Linux to test the client and launch my server code in Windows?

I understand I can start Windows processes from the WSL command line. And from the C test I can spawn new processes in Linux using `fork` and `execvp`, but will `execvp` work with launching a Windows process?

---

And if that works, can I also kill the child process I spawn later? So my Linux executable running a test on the client would spawn a Windows process (fork) that runs my server code on Windows. Then, when the test is complete, it kills the child (Windows) process.

Comment: Have you tried it? What is the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Your Windows drives should be available as `/mnt/c`, etc. So, for example, the path to Notepad is `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/notepad.exe`.